# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of LocationListener when using as external jar

Tags: android, jar, locationlistener

My goals is to get location data (lat, long ) in my project and use it as a library for another project. So I am extracting my classes.jar, renaming it and using as a jar for another project and I am getting below ART logical message.

```
art     : Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.icm.huddl.icmlib.LocationChangeListenerClass>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener;
```

In my Class

```
LocationChangeListenerClass implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

and the build.gradle(app)has

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.2'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
```

and build.gradle(project) has

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

And after all this I created a **google-services.json** and include in my library.jar

**NOTE: same code works fine as a stand alone Android project**

Comment: Forgot to mention : I am running my code on Tv with Nvidia Shield connected to use it as Android TV

Comment: I created an example POC for the same with one project containing LocationListiner code which is made into and .jar and imported as a .jar dependency in another project. And I get the same error as mentioned above, which basically means that while compiling and converting into .jar, LocationListner class is getting missed. Still haven't found any solution so looking for help from community.